# Dismissing two alertDialogs at once

Tags: android, xamarin

I have one dialog fragment, that calls another Alert dialog. I want that when I click on an item from the second one, they both are dismissed.

Inside of the first dialog, I have this code:

```
void ListViewVerListas_ItemLongClick (object sender, AdapterView.ItemLongClickEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] item_eliminar;

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder (this.Activity);
            item_eliminar = new string[]{"Eliminar"};
            ArrayAdapter ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, item_eliminar);

            ListView lista = new ListView (this.Activity);
            lista.Adapter = ListAdapter;


            lista.ItemClick+= Lista_ItemClick;


            alert.SetView (lista);

            posicao = e.Position;

            this.Activity.RunOnUiThread (() => {
                alert.Show();
            } );
            this.Dialog.Dismiss();

        }
        void Lista_ItemClick (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            pos = adapter.GetItemId (posicao);
            string aux="";
            int c = 0;
            string nome="";
            string auxiliar="";
            foreach (var linha in Lista) {

                auxiliar = linha.Split (new char[] { ' ' }) [0];
                if (c != pos) {
                    aux += linha + System.Environment.NewLine;

                } else {

                    nome = auxiliar;
                }
                c++;

            }
            mItems.RemoveAt (e.Position );

            adapter = new Ver_listas_adapter (this.Activity,Resource.Layout.listview_row_ver_listas, mItems);
            ListViewVerListas.Adapter = adapter;

            var path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var filename = Path.Combine(path, "Lista_de_Listas.txt");

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(path, nome + ".txt"));
            fi.Delete ();
            File.WriteAllText (filename, aux);
            //this.Dismiss ();
            this.Dismiss();

        }
```

How can I do this?